# Shortcut to mark directory as source

Tags: intellij-idea

In the current use case with intellij-idea 13.1.1, I try to only use the keyboard.
* I go in my project structure - Alt+1
* I create a "java" directory - Alt+insert
* I want to mark this directory as a source directory  ???

There is a menu item in the contextual menu: "Mark directory as"...
But I don't know how to invoke it from the keyboard.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do it from keyboard only.

```
* select the directory in the project panel    
* click "context menU" key  (I just discovered that one)  
* select "Mark Directory as"...
```

It is better, but selecting "Mark Directory as" menu item requires a few click, it would be faster to have a direct shortcut.
Do you know one?

Answer (score 2):

There's no direct keyboard shortcut to it, but you can do it by making use of the "Find Action by Name" shortcut.

1. Navigate to your folder structure by CTRL + F1.
2. Select the folder you wish to mark using your arrow keys.
3. Press CTRL + SHIFT + A, and type "Mark Directory As".  Hit Enter.
4. Mark the folder now selected as a sources directory.  You're done at that point.

Comment: When I do CTRL+SHIT+A, there is no entry for "Mark Directory As".

Comment: Since you were specifying ALT instead of Command, I presumed you were on a PC.  That said, be sure that the menu option you're opening states "Enter action or option name".

Comment: I am surprised, because I am on linux. CTRL+SHIFT+A open the right popup (Enter action...) but I can,t find the "Mark directory as" menu item :-(

Answer (score 0):

[image]
The most direct solution is using IDE, in case of Android studio.
1, At project panel.
File->Project Structure...
2, Project Settings:
Modules-> {your project}
Sources tab
Mark as: Source

3, Click Apply.